# How to use pushViewController and popViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to A viewcontroller switch another B viewcontroller,First time,I push(press GuestBook Button)and TableView get information ok,and press back Button ok, push(press GuestBook Button) again,JSON data `NSLog` have message,but tableview data not appear!
what's happen?

PS:i use storyboard!Have a custom cell xib!

A.m

```
- (IBAction)toHostGuestBook:(id)sender {
    hgbvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ToHostGuestBookSegue"];
    hgbvc.eventidStr = eventidStr;
    NSLog(@"hgbvc.eventidStr:%@",hgbvc.eventidStr);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:hgbvc animated:YES];

}
```

B.m

```
- (IBAction)backToHostMainEventDetail:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

B.m

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *GuestBookCellIdentifier = @"GuestBookCellIdentifier";

    static BOOL nibsRegistered = NO;
    if (!nibsRegistered) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GuestBookCell" bundle:nil];
        [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:GuestBookCellIdentifier];
        nibsRegistered = YES;
    }

    gbcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:GuestBookCellIdentifier];
    if (gbcell == nil) {
        gbcell = [[GuestBookCell alloc]
                   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                   reuseIdentifier:GuestBookCellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [messageRows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    gbcell.nicknameStr = [dict objectForKey:@"vusr"];
    gbcell.dateStr = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
    gbcell.messageStr = [dict objectForKey:@"message"];


    return gbcell;

}
```

Comment: i think u didn't load your table when popViewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this and Try

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.tableView reloadData]; //your table view name

}
```

Comment: Thank guys,i try to add code,but tabeview the same no information,i have custom cell xib,i use storyboard,Did you Whether it will affect?

Answer (score 0):

hgbvc the B controller is retained by the A controller. so, it doesn't released when the B controller poped out. When the B controller pushed again, the viewDidLoad method not called.

solution: extract the tableview load data method. call this method when you push B.

in B controller:

```
- (void)showDataWithEventId:(NSString *)eventId
{
    //retrive data 
    //table view reload
}
```

Comment: thanks guy!i add code when i push B have the same situation!         - (IBAction)toHostGuestBook:(id)sender {
    hgbvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ToHostGuestBookSegue"];
    hgbvc.eventidStr = eventidStr;
    NSLog(@"hgbvc.eventidStr:%@",hgbvc.eventidStr);
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:hgbvc animated:YES];
    [hgbvc.tv reloadData];
    
}

Comment: not the reloadData method of your table view, see the modified answer above.

Answer (score 0):

try to reload the table view data on below the code of popViewController this is work what you want

Comment: Thank guys!I try to add below code [self.tv reloadData] the same situation!                                                          - (IBAction)backToHostMainEventDetail:(id)sender {
    
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tv reloadData];
}